He was really hitting on me, with steamy looks and innuendos

He was really hitting on me, with steamy looks and innuendos.

What's the meaning of 'innuendos' here?
I know this word in terms of dictionary definitions but the meaning is not clear when it comes to interpreting the sentence.
"a statement which indirectly suggests that someone has done something immoral, improper, etc." is one of definitions.
In this definition, the sentence in question implies that he was threatening her with speaking bad things that she had done in the past for the sake of sleeping with her.
What's the exact meaning of the 'innuendos' in the given sentence?
Men had better say good things rather than bad things when they insinuate themselves into the target women.

Just the dictionary definition.  What is unclear? He was making innuendos.  Check that you are reading the definition of the countable noun.

a statement which indirectly suggests that someone has done something immoral, improper, etc. In this definition, the sentence in question implies that he was threatening her with speaking bad things that she had done in the past for the sake of sleeping with her.

The relevant definition (from Cambridge) is "(the making of) a remark or remarks that suggest something sexual [...] but do not refer to it directly"

@DanielRoseman has it. She: I ride my horse at weekends. He: I knew you liked a gallop! We Brits know all about innuendo. You should see our Christmas pantomimes, which appeal both to children and their parents (on different levels!) Examples here

https://www.dailymotion.com/video/x2ns6mn

innuendos is being used as a synonym for "suggestive remarks".   In this context, it's pretty clear that he man is not suggesting that she failed to report income on her 2022 tax filing.  Though perhaps in some circles blackmail would be an entrée.
